# Can I provision a MAAS node with an arbitrary install image?

Tags: maas

I'd like to provision machines using arbitrary install images (i.e. Ubuntu +1 daily ISOs.)  I know this is possible in cobbler, and I'm wondering if it can be done using the MAAS API or if I should just use cobbler directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could technically be able to do so, MAAS only know about Ubuntu Precise. In order to be able to do it, you would have to do the following:

1. Import a Quantal ISO.
2. Point the Cobbler profile to the newly imported Quantal Distro.
3. Deploy.

For MAAS eyes, you would still be deploying precise, but in reality you would be deploying Quantal. However, if you were to use juju you might find errors while using the charms.

This could help you to do some minor testing, but it is not yet recommended to do so. Quantal support will be added soon.

Comment: Well, right now we're in november and it seems quantal support is still missing =/